# Performance of Apache Math library version 3.3 vs 2.2

Tags: java, performance, apache-commons-math

I have some code that does physics modelling and uses Apache Math library version 2.2. Math library version 3.3 has superseded ver 2.2 by some 3 years now, and I was wanting to upgrade the library.

However, testing showed the new library to make the model take 20% longer to run. Much of the model run-time is spent doing Math.exp() functions, and we use FastMath.exp() where possible as it is much faster. However, FastMath.exp() also appears to be about 20% slower in Apache math3.

This is a real shame, as Apache math3 finally includes Erf.erfInv() which would mean we don't have to use a separate library for error functions. However, we cant afford to lose 20% speed. The use of unchecked exceptions in math3 is nice too, but we can simulate that by catching checked exceptions from v2 and re-throwing as unchecked.

- Does anyone know why math3 is slower in these places?
- Does anyone have any pressing reason why I should upgrade despite the performance impact?

If not, I wont be upgrading to math3 :-/

Comment: This is acknowledged upstream as [MATH-740 - Some "FastMath" functions are slow](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-740).

Comment: Yes, but .exp() is one of the functions that is faster in FastMath that Math in both v2.2 and v3.3. However, both Math.exp() and FastMath.exp() are slower in 3.3 than 2.2...